# mysql trigger update on number of affected rows condition

Tags: mysql

i want to make a trigger after update for a table. When update query is executed on this table, i want to make changes to some other table. So, i need to know if the number of affected rows are greater than 0.

exact scenario:

```
Table: table_user
userid (primary key)
no_changes_status (true means no update has been made on table_website for this userid)

Table: table_website
userid (reference key)
website_url (when the value of this field is changed, no_changes_status should be set to false)
```

I want to make a trigger on table_website which will check **number_of_affected_rows** for each insert and update. if **number_of_affected_rows is greater than 0**, then trigger will make no_changes_status to false.

I am unable to find any syntax/function which can be used to determine **number_of_affected_rows** for trigger.

Almost same question is asked at [MySQL forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,287324,287324) by someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible since a trigger operates row based (`FOR EACH ROW...`). You will have to do a `SELECT` first and see how many rows will be affected and then do whatever necessary. Solve it in your code, not in a trigger.

[Manual entry](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-trigger.html)

EDIT:

If it's just one row you can do something like:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER testref BEFORE INSERT ON table_website
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SELECT @aff_rows:=COUNT(*) FROM table_website WHERE yourCondition = sameConditionUsedForYourInsert
    AND (
    OLD.col1 != NEW.col1 OR
    OLD.col2 != NEW.col2 ...);
    IF @aff_rows > 0 THEN
       UPDATE table_user SET no_changes_status = whatever WHERE whatever;
    END IF;
  END;

$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I am targeting changes on one row only. in my case number_of_affected_rows will be 0 OR 1 only. Can you suggest some better way based on this information?

Comment: I also thought this way: **IF OLD.website_url != NEW.website_url** and it worked fine. but when this table will have multiple columns, i will have to check for each and every column. Therefore I am looking for a better way which checks for all the columns at once.

Comment: @DhairyaVora Haven't seen your comment before updating answer. I don't think there's a more comfortable way.

Comment: updated answer will change no_changes_status to 1 even in case of same value for website_url. I mean if database has value "www.google.com" and an update query is fired for same url, this will change no_changes_status to 1

Comment: You are right, but if you want to avoid that, you will have to check like you did each column (updated answer to reflect that).

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done in a trigger on update, as it is called for each row.

#### Solution proposed:

I hope you have a user-defined procedure that does this update, if not then I advise you to create one such proc.

In this proc, after running the update query you can get the **number of rows affected** using

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

And you can use this for further processing. [`RowCount()` manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count).

Hope this helps.